# Libgdx Box2D body and Sprite alignment issue

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I have a problem with Libgdx framework. I tried to create a class extends Sprite, but when I render it I realize that `body` doesn't align with the sprite texture.

Here is an image showing the problem:

[image: here is the image]

You can see the code below:

```
public class GamePlay implements Screen {

private GameMain game;
private OrthographicCamera mainCamera;
private Viewport viewport;

private OrthographicCamera b2dcam;
private Box2DDebugRenderer debugRenderer;
private World world;

private Texture background;

private Brick brick;
float timer = 0;


public GamePlay(GameMain game)
{
    this.game = game;

    mainCamera = new OrthographicCamera(GameInfo.WIDTH, GameInfo.HEIGHT);
    mainCamera.position.set(GameInfo.WIDTH/2, GameInfo.HEIGHT/2,0);

    viewport = new FitViewport(GameInfo.WIDTH, GameInfo.HEIGHT, mainCamera);

    b2dcam = new OrthographicCamera();
    b2dcam.setToOrtho(false, GameInfo.WIDTH/GameInfo.PPM, GameInfo.HEIGHT / GameInfo.PPM);
    b2dcam.position.set(GameInfo.WIDTH/2f, GameInfo.HEIGHT/2f, 0);

    debugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
    world = new World(new Vector2(0,0), true);

    background = new Texture("BGS/GameBG.png");

    brick = new Brick(world, "my brick");
    brick.setBricksPosition(cgp(20), cgp(20));


}

//region Screen Methods
@Override
public void show() {

}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    game.getBatch().begin();
    game.getBatch().draw(background,0,0);
    brick.draw(game.getBatch());
    game.getBatch().end();

    debugRenderer.render(world, b2dcam.combined);

    world.step(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), 6,2);
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void hide() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    background.dispose();

}
//endregion


private float cgp(int gridPos)
{
    return gridPos * GameInfo.gridSize;
}}



public class Brick extends Sprite {

private World world;
private Body body;
private String name;
private Fixture fixture;

public  Brick(World world, String name)
{
    super(new Texture("Bricks/brick.png"));
    this.world = world;
    this.name = name;


}

void createBody()
{
    BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
    bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;

    bodyDef.position.set((getX() - getWidth())/ GameInfo.PPM, (getY() + getHeight()/2)/ GameInfo.PPM);

    body = world.createBody(bodyDef);

    PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();

    shape.setAsBox((getWidth()/2)/GameInfo.PPM, (getHeight()/2)/GameInfo.PPM);

    FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
    fixtureDef.shape = shape;

    fixture = body.createFixture(fixtureDef);

    shape.dispose();

}

public void setBricksPosition(float x, float y)
{
    setPosition(x,y);
    createBody();
}

public void draw(SpriteBatch batch)
{
    batch.draw(this, getX(), getY());
}}
```

Comment: See help topics, and reduce code to an MCVE : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Finally I find the solution.
The problem happens because of my PPM value. I set it to 100 and when you divide it to screen size it doesnt make a whole number. so I changed it to 160 which can be divided both 800 and 480 and the problem was solved.

Comment: Did you try setting PPM to a float (100.0f, for example?) bodydef position is a Vector, which accepts floats and sprite getX and getWidth return floats. Setting PPM to an int to be divisible by only specific screen sizes could limit you later.

Comment: Yes, thank you Peter. This is the right solution.. :)

Answer (score 0):

The box2d debug render (shows the actual position of the body) and your sprite are "pretty close", so I'm guessing you're not far off and the problem is likely in your calculation/translation of box2d position vs. screen position vs. pixels vs. meters.

You do PPM conversions, so that's good. I didn't have time to look through all your code, but as the 2 items are very close, check your calculations again. This line:

```
bodyDef.position.set((getX() - getWidth())/ GameInfo.PPM, (getY() + getHeight()/2)/ GameInfo.PPM);
```

caught my eye. Render debug and sprite are correct as far as y is concerned, but off on x. Your height uses getHeight()/2, but getWidth does not divide by 2. Perhaps that's all your missing (divide Width by 2 as well)?

Comment: thank you for your answer but I realize that I deleted it by mistake. When I divide it by 2 the result is not aligned too. there should be another problem but i can not get it..

Comment: OK, not sure if you're saying the code you posted doesn't line up with the image. At any rate, I still think its in the calculation. Look for what is different, or just try brute force changing things until they "line up". As I said, you're close, but I don't have the time handy to look at the code. For instance, you subtract getWidth() but add getHeight(), that's a difference too I notices. (I'm taking stabs in the dark now too)

Comment: thanks for you help Peter. I will check the code again :)